# jquery, my variable has 2 values

Tags: jquery, variables, load

in a page test.php I'm loading content.php like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.test', function () {
        $('#content').load('content.php');
});
```

in content.php I have this Jquery code:

```
$(function() {
   var nb = 10;
   $(document).on('click', '.trigger', function () {
         alert(nb);
         nb +=10;
   });
   $(document).on('click', '.exit', function () { $('#content').html(''); });
});
```

when I'm clicking for the first time on #content nb as the value 10 and I can increment it by clicking on it, for exemple I'm clicking 3 times on it so its value is 40. Then I'm closing the div by clicking on .exit, and I'm reloading content.php by clicking on #content. Now I have two alert: nb as the value 10 but it also has the value 40, how come it still has the value 40?

Comment: You need to remove the `click` event using `.off()` method.

Comment: It is because of the event is registered to the document object, when the `'#content'` loaded first there is one event handler registered then when it is removed the event handler is not removed

Comment: @DreamEater where should I just this method exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because when you are removing `#content`, you are not removing the registered event handler.

You can do so by using [.off](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
$(function() {
    var fn = function() {
        alert(nb);
        nb += 10;
    };

    var nb = 10;

    $(document).on('click', '.trigger', fn);
    $(document).on('click', '.exit', function() {
        $('#content').html('');
        $(document).off('click', '.trigger', fn);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are executing your anonymous function two times. So there are two variables `nb` in different scopes. And your event handler is bound again after loading your view. So unbind it first:

```
$(document).off('click.MyEventHandler').on('click.MyEventHandler', '.trigger', function () {
     alert(nb);
     nb +=10;
});
```

I put event in a namespace `.MyEventHandler` to avoid to disable other click events. But actually you should better use the closest parent content as event listener. So:

```
$('#content').off('click.MyEventHandler').on('click.MyEventHandler', '.trigger', function () {
     alert(nb);
     nb +=10;
});
```